Trivialization of the tangent bundle of sphere
Can someone give an explicit trivialization of the tangent bundle of the sphere?
I know that the tangent bundle $\pi:T\mathbb{S}^2\to \mathbb{S}^2$ of the sphere $\mathbb{S}^2\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ is not trivial, by the hairy ball theorem. But, I would like an explicit construction of the trivialization $\{\phi_i\}_{i\in I}$, where $\phi_i:T\mathbb{S}^2|_{U_i}\to U_i\times\mathbb{R}^2$ are local trivializations, $U_i$ is some open set in $\mathbb{S}^2$ and $T\mathbb{S}^2|_{U_i}=\pi^{-1}(U_i)$. Since $T\mathbb{S}^2$ is nontrivial, #$I>1$.
Maybe this is a very classical question, but I could not find the answer anywhere.
Thank you for any help.

Pick your favourite charts on $S^2$ and use the associated trivializations of $TS^2$.

For any manifold $M$, whenever $(U; x^1,\ldots, x^n)$ is a chart, we build a local trivialization $$\pi^{-1}(U) \ni (p,v) \mapsto (p, ({\rm d}x^1|_p(v),\ldots, {\rm d}x^n|_p(v)))\in U\times \mathbb{R}^n.$$There is nothing particular about the sphere here. If this is not explicit enough for you, just carry this out using spherical coordinates or stereographic coordinates in the sphere.
(Oof: Ben beat me to it by 30 seconds.)

Of course you can find the answer plenty of places. You need local trivializations over thickened hemispheres and then the Jacobian of the composition $\phi_1\circ\phi_2^{-1}$ on the overlap.

Thank you all. I would like to compute the trivialization with respect to the atlas consisting of six charts, those that map ${x_i>0}\to{ x_i=0}$ and the same for ${x_i<0}$. I’ll try to give an answer. Thank you again.

@IvoTerek I understand that this construction work for tangent bundle. Is there any change to have similar constructions for other vector bundle? Namely a rank-$2$ bundle over a 6 dimensional manifold?

Thanks to the comments, I think that an explicit trivialization can be the following.
Consider the atlas $\mathcal{A}=\{U_i,\varphi_i\}_{i=1}^3\cup\{V_j,\psi_j\}_{j=1}^3$, where $U_i=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\mathbb{S}^2:x_i>0\}$, $V_j=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\mathbb{S}^2:x_j<0\}$ and $\varphi_1(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\psi_1(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_2,x_3)$ and analogously for $\varphi_i,\psi_i$ with $i=2,3$. Let us deal only with $U_1$, the other cases are similar. We can trivialize $T\mathbb{S}^2$ on $U_1$ as follows:
$$
\phi_1:\pi^{-1}(U_1)\to U_1\times\mathbb{R}^2,\\
(p;v_1,v_2,v_3)\mapsto (p;v_2,v_3).
$$
Note that, for any fixed $p\in U_1$ the restiction $\phi_1|_{T_p\mathbb{S}^2}$ is an isomorphism, as for all $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)\in T_p\mathbb{S}$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ cannot be both zero.

Let $i,j,k$ be an orthonormal basis on $R^3$. If $x$ is a vector, then $x\wedge i$ is a vector orthogonal to $x$. On can therefore construct three vector fields on the sphere, $I(x)= x\wedge i, J(x)= x\wedge j, K(x)= x\wedge k$. It is easy to see that these 3 vectors fields are tangent to the sphere, and that at each point they generated the tangent plane of the sphere at $x$.

I agree with you, but what is the point regarding the trivialization of $T\mathbb{S}^2$?

It splits $S^2$ in 3 sets with a trivialisation $I  = 0$ is trivialised by $J,K$, and so on.

What do you mean by a trivialization $I=0$ is trivialized by $J,K$? I thought that a trivialization was a choice of an open set $U$ in $\mathbb{S}^2$ and a homeomorphism $\phi:\pi^{-1}(U)\to U\times V$ such that for any $p\in U$, the restriction of $\phi$ to $\pi^{-1}(p)$ is a linear isomorphism between the fiber at $p$ and some vector space $V$. It seems you have different ideas in mind. Could you explain a little bit?
